# setattribute to addEventListener

Tags: javascript

i want to change

```
newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "select-one":
```

`newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute("onchange","showUser(this.value,"+xx+");");


            }`

with event listener so it can contain 2 function
showuser and showrole

but please tell me how can i do that

Comment: And what is your question and the problem?

Comment: A side question: Which facts had spoken for to include two functions within one function?

Comment: The question is how to add 2 function because i have to run 2 diferent function with almost same code just diferent div id to showpassword and role

Answer (score 4):

You should use `addEventListener` instead of `.setAttribute`

This way you can set more functionalities without any problem

Comment: newcell.childNodes[0].addEventListener("onclick", my_JS_function, false);

i tried that and still did not work